# Cambiar el color de un Floating Action Button con animación

Tags: android

Quisiera saber como cambiar el color de un Floating Action Button con animación, lo intenté con `ObjectAnimator` pero no me cambia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir que luego de hacer click cambie el color del botón, este es mi código:

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(floatingActionButton, "Color").start();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### programaticamente sería mediante un **[ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)** y el método **[setBackgroundTintList()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))** :

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[0]}, new int[]{0xff00ff00});
            floatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(csl);  
        }
    });
```

**Es muy importante definir el [Alpha](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) para que tu color cambie!.**

También puedes cargar tu color desde `colors.xml`:

```
 <color name="mi_color_verde">#FF00FF00</color>
```

por lo tanto así cambiarias el color:

```
int miColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.mi_color_verde);
ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[0]}, new int[]{miColor});
floatingActionButton.setBackgroundTintList(csl);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### También existen 2 formas mediante la propiedad `app:backgroundTint` o simplemente define tu imagen de botón con otro color mediante `android:src` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    app:borderWidth="1dp">
```

Incluso puedes definir tu propia imagen y cambiar el color con `app:backgroundTint`, pero asegura que tu imagen tenga la transparencia adecuada.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres hacer mediante código puedes colocar esto en el evento del  botón(ejemplo):

```
tuBotón.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));
```